# is Spring for android useful?

Tags: android, spring-android

a little question about the project of spring for android.
I have to develop an android app that use RESTful Service on a Spring developed server.
Now it is useful to start with spring for android? 
Has this project a future? Because the last release was December 2012.

Are there a good tutorial about how develop an android app that has to use restful services?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Spring for android is useful if you need:

- A Rest Client for Android
- Auth support for accessing secure APIs

Given your question you say that you will use a RESTful Service. So my answer is that it can be useful to you.

Spring Android will not provide Depencency Injection support, Transaction Support, etc, etc.

I use an android opensource framework that integrates with spring android and simplify your coding: [Android Annotations](http://androidannotations.org/). This will reduce your code and give you a sort of Depencency Injection.

An other option to get Dependecy Injection support is [roboguice](https://github.com/roboguice/roboguice).

Here you are a tutorial that explain you how to create a RESTful android application with spring: http://blogs.burnsidedigital.com/2012/08/how-to-create-restful-http-for-android-in-4-easy-steps-using-spring/